# How to hide [value] in datalist in angular?

Tags: angular, html-select

I try to make search form for movie database with dropdown datalist with search results, and when click to option I want to move to movie page. But I can't figure out how to hide [value] string in <option [value]>.
Here is my code:

```
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2"
         required
         list="foundMovies"
         [(ngModel)]="searchString"
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
         (ngModelChange)="startSearch($event)"
         type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">

  <datalist id="foundMovies">
    <option *ngFor="let movie of foundMovies"
            [value]="movie.id"
    > {{movie.title}} </option>
  </datalist>
  <button
    (click)="submitForm()"
    class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" >Найти</button>
</form>
```

and here is ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MovieService} from '../../../model/movie.service';
import {Movie} from '../../../model/movie';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-search-form',
  templateUrl: './movie-search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-search-form.component.css']
})
export class MovieSearchFormComponent implements OnInit {
  searchString: Movie;
  foundMovies: Movie[];

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  submitForm(): void{
    console.log(this.searchString);
  }

  startSearch(search): void {
    console.log(search);

    if (search.length >= 3) {
      this.movieService.searchForMovies(search)
        .subscribe(result => {
          if (result.length){
            this.foundMovies = result;
          }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

the main problen that when I use [ngValue] with options I can't get movie.id in      startSearch(search): void {
console.log(search); string, I allways get the name of the movie, and if I use [value] instead I get movie.id when choose option, but I can't hide movie.id on dropdown list of options.
So the question is how to hide movie.id, when I use [value] with options, or how can I use [ngValue] such way, to get movie.id when I select some option.
Using [ngValue]
[image: Using [ngValue]]

Using [value]
[image]

Comment: What versión of angular you are running?

Comment: I use Angular 10

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code ( I recommend always specified the version of angular that you are running)

With the new line I put,now you have the id of the movie.

**ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MovieService} from '../../../model/movie.service';
import {Movie} from '../../../model/movie';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-search-form',
  templateUrl: './movie-search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-search-form.component.css']
})
export class MovieSearchFormComponent implements OnInit {
  searchString: Movie;
  foundMovies: Movie[];

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  submitForm(): void{
    console.log(this.searchString);
  }

  startSearch(search): void {
    idMovie: number = this.foundMovies.find(x => x.title === search)[0].id // WARNING NEW LINE
    console.log(search);

    if (search.length >= 3) {
      this.movieService.searchForMovies(search)
        .subscribe(result => {
          if (result.length){
            this.foundMovies = result;
          }
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem that I can get 2 or 3 movies with the same name, and If I use [value]="movie.id" I get the movie.id in "startSearch" movie and can deal with it, but I have annoying movie.id in datalist. I think that dataList is not a good idea for this and I should looking for custop dropdown component to get what I want. But thank's for watching and helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

After an hours of lookup I found that usage of dataList is not a good solution in my case. So I found answer for my question here : [enter link description here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead/examples)

Here is my input:

```
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">

  <input id="typeahead-prevent-manual-entry"  type="text" class="form-control"
         [(ngModel)]="movie"
         [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
         (ngModelChange)="jumpToMovie($event)"
         [ngbTypeahead]="movieSearch"
         [inputFormatter]="formatter"
         [resultFormatter]="formatter"
         [editable]='false' />
  <hr>
  <pre>Model: {{ movie | json }}</pre>
  <button
    (click)="submitForm()"
    class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" >Search</button>
</form>
```

Also I have to add library "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "7.0.0",
And white `movieSearch` and `formatter` methods in ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MovieService} from '../../../model/movie.service';
import {Movie} from '../../../model/movie';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';
import {switchMap, catchError, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-search-form',
  templateUrl: './movie-search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-search-form.component.css']
})
export class MovieSearchFormComponent implements OnInit {
  movie: Movie;
  searchString: string;
  foundMovies: Movie[];

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  submitForm(): void{
    console.log(this.searchString);
  }

  formatter = (movie: Movie) => movie.title;

  movieSearch = (text$: Observable<string>) => {

    return text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      // switchMap allows returning an observable rather than maps array
      switchMap( (searchText) =>  {
        this.searchString = searchText;
        return this.movieService.searchForMovies(searchText).pipe(
            // Reduce size of result array
            map( data => data.slice(0, 7 )
          ));
      }),
      catchError(err => '')
    );
  }

  jumpToMovie(event): void{
    console.log(event);
  }

}
```

So now, when I click on suggested links this.movie becomes an object, and I can move to movie page I looked for.